# Kusto Query: Join multiple tables

Tags: join, azure-data-explorer

‎
[TablesA, TableB, TableC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Kgvb.jpg)

After joining the tables: TableA, TableB, TableC using Kusto Query how to show the value of column: IsPriLoc in the column: PriLoc and IsSecLoc in SecLoc. Below is the expected result

[ExpectedResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElfEM.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a couple of assumptions (regarding data types for example) but this query delivers the required results:

[Link to execute on Kusto help cluster](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4WSTWuDQBCG7/6KQXJIIBTiqocGD%20bDIgklNM2plJLabWqwWtztzR9f9%20ONWlK6e3BmntF933ELLimmiN6Ost2vBafx3SFdvew2tyRknZenKd0fP3mXrbjIkE3oyaF2uTN3Su4jF1IHqqUNDPKAPCAPiAExIAbkA/lAPlAAFAAFQCFQCBS6mjzPnaJ1urjiNOk53dX5tsq6fM%20zXj50a3p1aNpmA1sGsw6zgX6Dgw7Dg1W6/EdpKn5rTcUfas0PeDis1TOJt/v1YMi2gpb%20IK%208g0EqfQvSpYa%20y7wqaawztZZ0CRv6qqszzyRZCxhyBAeYcgQDk7kTk9PQucpLdVD76VHB3%20WNvZgURTSq89OHrSSbHwR8cBLFAgAA)

```
let A = datatable (GUID_PK: string, Name: string, Desc: string) [
    "1", "Test1", "Desc1",
    "2", "Test2", "Desc2",
    "3", "Test3", "Desc3",
    "4", "Test4", "Desc4",
    "5", "Test5", "Desc5",
    "6", "Test6", "Desc6"
    ];
let B = datatable (GUID_FK: string, PriLoc: string, SecLoc: string) [
    "1", "PriLoc1", "SecLoc1",
    "3", "PriLoc3", "SecLoc3",
    "5", "PriLoc5", "SecLoc5",
    ];
let C = datatable (GUID_FK: string, IsPriLoc: string, IsSecLoc: string) [
    "2", "TRUE", "FALSE",
    "4", "FALSE", "TRUE",
    "6", "TRUE", "FALSE",
    ];
let BC = B 
    | union (
        C 
        | project GUID_FK, PriLoc=IsPriLoc, SecLoc=IsSecLoc);
A 
| join BC on $left.GUID_PK == $right.GUID_FK
```

Comment: Thank you Rony for your prompt response. This is working